# Overriding library constructor with unwanted behavior

Tags: java, math, inheritance, apache-commons

I'm doing some basic computation using the Apache Commons Library, and I have a 2x2 symmetric RealMatrix for which I need to compute the EigenDecomposition.  The matrix is as follows:

```
{{10.387035702893005, 0.14862451664049367},
{0.14862451664049442, -5.1952457826500815}}
```

The top right and bottom left elements, of type double, are supposed to be identical, and you'll notice that they almost are.  When I pass the matrix to a new instance of EigenDecomposition, however, I'll get an exception.  isSymmetric() evaluates false, and because the constructor passes in 'true' as a parameter, the isSymmetric() method raises an exception.  I basically need to bypass this check.  What are my options?  Thanks!

```
public EigenDecomposition(final RealMatrix matrix,
                              final double splitTolerance)  {
    if (isSymmetric(matrix, true)) {
        transformToTridiagonal(matrix);
        findEigenVectors(transformer.getQ().getData());
    }
}
```

N.B. The split tolerance parameter, which one might think specifies a tolerance level, is merely a dummy parameter.

Comment: How are you constructing that matrix?

Comment: It's from a bit of computation.  Taking a large matrix, finding it's maximum off-diagonal's row & column, then forming the 2x2 matrix from
[[ii, ij],[ji, jj]].  The numbers in the larger matrix at ij and ji are made slightly different, I imagine, through the later computational steps which involve a few mutations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a numerical error - the values are almost identical, but not exactly. A quick and dirty solution could be:

Check if the two values equal each other using the condition: `Math.abs(matrix[0][1] - matrix[1][0]) < DELTA`. where `DELTA` is your tolerance factor (what is the maximum you can tolerate so the matrix will be considered symetric).

If it is - assign `matrix[0][1] = matrix[1][0]`

It is easy to see that a matrix that suffices the condition should now be symetric by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you override `isSymmetric` and then get the second paramter to be ignored. YOu could then call your own `isSymmetric` method

For example

```
@override
public boolean isSymmetric(RealMatrix m, Boolean b) {
     return _isSymmetric(m);
}
```

where `_isSymmetric(m)` is your own implementation. You could then compare the double values in any way you see fit. I would recommend using delta rather than a straight == as double values are very rarely exactly equaly but usually are equal enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the two values are supposed to be equal, can you just copy one over the top of the other?

```
matrix[0][1] = matrix[1][0];
```